# Copy all lines hit by search in notepad++

Tags: search, text, copy, notepad++

I have a huge file with my db dump which is like the small snippet shown below.

```
903 09-JAN-14   4   2   "false" "false" "false" 7505    7459    2139    66.51   0.18    69.72   1
903 09-JAN-14   5   3   "false" "false" "false" 7468    7415    2173    66.24   0.37    70.19   4
860 17-FEB-13   1   1   "false" "false" "false" 7014    6973    2371    67.21   0.97    68.31   16
860 17-FEB-13   2   2   "false" "false" "false" 6992    6954    2401    66.95   0.62    68.78   8
891 10-DEC-13   1   1   "false" "false" "false" 1010    1001    10965   17.75   11.3    71.49   505
903 17-DEC-13   5   3   "false" "false" "false" 7468    7415    2173    66.24   0.37    70.19   4
903 10-JAN-14   7   4   "false" "false" "false" 7421    7380    2225    65.83   0.01    71.14   0
860 11-JAN-14   1   1   "false" "false" "false" 7014    6973    2371    67.21   0.97    68.31   16
```

I want to copy all the lines with `903` in it. Is there a way to do it in notepad++?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do:

- `Search > Mark...` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
- Find what : `^903\b`
- Tick `Bookmark line` and `Regular Expression`
- <kbd>Mark All</kbd> : All the lines that begin with `903` are now marked.
- <kbd>Copy Marked Text</kbd>

After that:

- goto destination file then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: This should work. But "^903\b" is not bookmarking all the the 903 values. I want to get atleast all the lines starting with 903.Can you please suggest a way to filter it

Comment: @RBz: It bookmarks all lines that begin with `903`, isn't that what you want?

Comment: That is exactly what i want. But this search is not marking all lines that begin with 903 :(

Comment: @RBz: Really strange. May be there is a non printable character before `903`. could you edit your question and add lines that are not marked?

Comment: Yes i didn't checked that. Got it fixed :)
And between Signet is Bookmark in english :D

Comment: Likely the functionality or naming has changed in years since.  But still works; in step 3 instead check "Bookmark Line" and later "Search > Bookmark > Copy bookmarked lines"